# Why are IIS7 features missing on Win7 Home Premium compared to Win7 Pro?

Tags: iis, iis-7

I have two computers, home and work. The home computer runs Windows 7 Home Premium and work computer has Windows 7 Professional. Both have IIS7 installed on.

On the left hand side of the image you can see my home computer iis features on/off screen and on the right hand side my work computer's iis features. Sory for my home computer language is turkish but I matched corresponding items in english.

My question is why left side has only 4 security features whereas right side has 8. How can I add missing fetures?

[image]

Comment: The difference is the version of windows 7

Comment: Indeed. There's a fair gap between Win7 Home Premium and Professional which probably explains the discrepancy.

Comment: You might want to check out [IIS Express](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview), although I don’t know if it supports these specific features.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The IIS feature set in Home Premium is not the same as the IIS feature set in Pro.

So they are missing *because you're using Home Premium*. If you want domain-related and other advanced features for IIS, then you need a more advanced version of Windows (i.e.: Pro, or Server).

For a comparison list of available IIS features per Windows 7/2008 version, see this MS article: [Available Web Server (IIS) Role Services in IIS 7.5](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc753473.aspx).

Specifically, check the "*Security Features*" section which covers the exact features you are asking about:

[image]